# Another Guice + Jersey error NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jersey, guice, hk2

Well, GeneralUtilities does not even have the method getSystemProperty so not so weird it fails.

What is the best way to handle this?
Deploying on Liberty Profile.

Error:

```
[1/12/16 15:01:58:482 CET] 00000027 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              E SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [Jersey Web Application] in application [Agent-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/general/GeneralUtilities.getSystemProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.<clinit>(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:122)
  at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.initialize(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:66)
  at org.jvnet.hk2.external.generator.ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorGeneratorImpl.java:98)
  at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:312)
  at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:268)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:338)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:171)
      at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:363)
      at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:332)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1423)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1180)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1148)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1054)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6448)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApplication(DynamicVirtualHost.java:441)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startWebApplication(WebContainer.java:980)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.WebContainer.startModule(WebContainer.java:804)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.web.internal.WebModuleHandlerImpl.deployModule(WebModuleHandlerImpl.java:102)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModule(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:874)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployModules(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:834)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:821)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.war.internal.WARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(WARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:80)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:139)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1168)
      at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:781)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1143)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:618)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

JerseyConfig

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceBridge;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceIntoHK2Bridge;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public JerseyConfig(ServiceLocator locator) {
        packages("no.services.agent");

        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(locator);
        // add your Guice modules.
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule());
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = locator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
    }
}
```

SelftestResource

```
@Path("/")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public class SelftestResource {

    @GET
    public Response selftest(){
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.services.agent.guice.JerseyConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I bet the versions of hk2 brought in by the jersey-bom and the guice-bridge versions are not the same.  Can you do a mvn dependency:tree and see the versions of hk2 being used?

Comment: If you want to check the poor man's way, comment out the guice-bridge dependency, and look at your jars to see what version of HK2 dependencies are pulled in by Jersey. Then change the guice-bridge version accordingly. I'm about 99.5% percent sure jwells131313 is right.

Comment: That's correct. jersey-container-servlet is using 2.4.0-b31. Isn't it weird to have dependencies to beta in a release?

Comment: hk2 build releases are used by Jersey a lot in order to get fixes and new features (we don't really consider them to be beta, since they undergo just as much testing as normal hk2 releases, which only happen about once a year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said I believe the fix is to use the 2.4.0-b31 version of the guice-bridge